# Run jobscheduler all the time (doze or not)

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

How can I run the jobscheduler in doze or non doze mode i.e I want to run the bg job all the time. Is it possible?

```
JobInfo jobInfo
      = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000L)
        .setExtras(bundle)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: Do you want to execute exactly at specific time, use FCM

Answer (score 3):

There is tow way to implement what you want.

1. Use alarm manager with [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setexactandallowwhileidle) or [setAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setandallowwhileidle)
2. Use  [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

I personally suggest you please try with workManager.

Comment: WorkManager when using JobScheduler too is limited by this.